# Apply decimal format to a CellType.Formula

Tags: excel, apache-poi, java-7, formulas

I've recently update my POI lib to 3.17 and since then when I have a **CellType.FORMULA** I can't do the following:

```
public static void writeDecimal(Cell cell) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
    String pattern = "#0.00";
    DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
    decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    BigDecimal bigDecimal;
    try {
        bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());
        Double value = bigDecimal.doubleValue();
        cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
        cell.setCellValue(value);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.FINE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I get this error **Cannot get a STRING value from a NUMERIC formula cell**, because of this *bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());*

With 3.7 library I was able to execute this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the cell in the file itself is formatted to be a numeric cell. Assuming this cell will either always be a String or a Number, you should be able to modify your code just a little bit to get it to work.

You'll just need to check if it is a String cell first, and if it is, do things the way you're currently doing them. If it is a Numeric cell, you'll need to make your new `BigDecimal` from that number. I haven't worked much with `BigDecimal`, but I think the following code should work:

```
try {
    if(cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.STRING) {
        bigDecimal = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(cell.getStringCellValue());
    } else {
        //Assuming here that cell.getCellTypeEnum() == CellType.NUMERIC 
        bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(cell.getNumericCellValue());
    }
    Double value = bigDecimal.doubleValue();
    cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
    cell.setCellValue(value);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    Logger.getGlobal().log(Level.FINE, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

As an aside, is the `BigDecimal` necessary here? You seem to create it and then just get the `Double` value from it. You might be able to optimize this code by removing the `BigDecimal` stuff.